# machine learning training data structure

Tags: machine-learning

I have a question on machine learning training data.

Is there a way to structure the data so that the algorithm learns to make associations between data points. For example, if I hypothetically wanted to train the algorithm on what cats eat, how could I structure the training data so that the algorithm learns to associate cats with the food they eat?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're beginning to study machine learning. Let's expand on your example. There are two questions I think you might be asking here

(1) How do I figure out what cats like to eat? 
(2) How can I predict what a cat will eat if I know some extra facts about that cat? How do I structure data to accomplish this?

(1) This is the interpretation that Thomas Pinetz is referring to. To answer the question "what do cats like to eat" you don't need what most people would consider "machine learning." You can carry out a survey, and then use a test for statistical association. But I don' think that's what your asking for here...

(2) This is machine learning. This is not just about structuring data. **Note that everything below is wildly oversimplified.** Training data for machine learning is usually structured in terms of "instances." Suppose you have two kinds of food ("kibbles", and "tuna") and consider this example:

```
Cat / Features | eye-color | coat-color | ear-length-cm | **food**  | 
----           | ----      | ----       | ----          |  ---      | 
Socks          | "green"   | "brown"    | 3.0           | "kibbles" | 
Jimmy          | "blue"    | "gray"     | 3.7           | "tuna"    |
Snowball       | "green"   | "white"    | 2.9           | "kibbles" |
MrTumnus       | "blue"    | NA         | 3.1           | "tuna"    | 
Tosca          | "blue"    | "orange"   | 3.2           | "kibbles" | 
...            | ...       | ...        | ...           | ...       |
```

(One would hope for a bigger training set than this...) 
Each row of the above is an "instance." The three middle columns are features, facts about each cat. The last column is the food that the cat in question likes to eat, usually called the "class label." The first column is the name of the cat, which I made up for fun. It's useless information, but it lets us refer to our instances more easily here.

Your goal in this case would be to use the middle three columns, your features, to predict the class label. Data structured like this is a common starting point for a machine learning problem.

Now when you chose a way of attacking the problem, you'll be faced with some extra issues: 
(1) The MrTumnus instance has missing data, his "coat-color" is NA.
(2) You have both continuous (ear-length-cm) and discrete (eye-color, coat-color) features, depending on the algorithms you throw at this problem, using both kinds of data may be difficult.

Let's suppose you only consider your discrete features (eye-color, and coat-color). Some machine learning algorithm we can imagine might take this data, and compute probabilities like these:

1. P(eye-color = "green", food = "kibbles")
2. P(coat-color = "white", food = "tuna")
3. P(coat-color = "white", eye-color="blue", food="tuna")
4. etc. you can see where this is going.

This then gives us a model CatFood(eye-color, coat-color) which can return the food that the cat is most likely to enjoy, given eye-color, and coat-color. More questions: what if an eye-color or coat-color is supplied that we haven't seen before? Scratching the surface.

Then, when you have a new cat in front of you, and you want to find out what it might like to eat, based on its eye-color and coat-color, you would collect the data you need, and apply your model. Here's your new instance:

```
Cat / Features | eye-color | coat-color | **food**  | 
----           | ----      | ----       |  ---      | 
Oswald         | "blue"    | "orange"   |    ?      |
```

Suppose now we apply our model, CatFood("blue", "organge"). It goes back to the probabilities that were computed on our training data, and will tell us what food, according to the model, the cat is most likely to want to eat.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and for taking the time to write this example. It helps me understand it a lot. Could I take the same approach if I wanted to train the algorithm to make associations between two elements. For example, the best course of action given a specific problem? So, given problem A, solution B is the best one?

Comment: If you want to evaluate the performance of an approach, A, and compare it to another approach, B, you need "validation." There are many ways to do this; the simplest (to explain) is to have a *second* independent dataset for which you know the class labels, and which you do **not** use for training. You can then evaluate the performance of A, B (accuracy, false positives, false negatives etc.) on this new dataset, and decide which method performs best for your application.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have another scenario I would like to ask about. How would I structure the training data if I wanted to train a model on associating two elements. For example, a food with its recipe to then be able to pass the recipe to the model and for it to output the food or vice versa. So, if I input the recipe for cupcakes the model is able to tell me that the food corresponding to this recipe is cupcakes, or if I input cupcakes, the model is able to output the recipe. Thank you.

Comment: Prev. comment was accident, will del. First, if the recipe that maps to 'cupcakes' is invariant, then this isn't machine learning.I think you want to map a bunch of recipes for cupcakes (red velvet, chocolate, vanilla) to "cupcakes", and then map "cupcakes" to some 'base-recipe' etc. Without thinking too much, maybe (1) Two models, apply one or the other, or (2) You'd want to add extra layers to the architecture of your model, think of it like a decision tree/graph (e.g. first decide if query is a recipe or a food,... etc.). Sounds like you're working your way towards a neural network.

Answer (score -1):

This is pure statistics. Machine Learning is the art of making predictions about the future of things. If you wanted to predict what your cat is eating next than you could apply a machine learning algorithm.

But you want to discover a correspondence between what cats eat. If you really want to know this you should ask a couple people with cats on what they are eating and use some statistical model to find the mean.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.